# Vertical alignment in css of multiple elements (How to achieve this layout)

Tags: html, css

[image]

One thing I've been struggling with in CSS3 is layouts. 
I've read this blog post - http://www.toptal.com/css/css-layout-primer-from-classic-approaches-to-the-latest-techniques - and its been helpful for over layout techniques. However, I become a bit stuck when moving down to specific elements. I'm a backend dev by trade so its not my area of expertise.

E.g. given the above image there are rows and rows of these on a page. What would the ideal div structure be and what SASS/CSS would be good to match.

```
<div class="container">   
  <div class="team1"> Vasco </div>  
  <div class="logo1"> <img>logo image</img> </div>   
    <div class="status"> Finished </div>
  <div class="logo2"> <img>logo image</img> </div> 
  <div class="team2"> flamengo </div> 
</div>
```

I've toyed with the above div structure and a mixture of floats, inline blocks etc... But I'm now a bit clueless. Equally I can change this to spans, or whatever required.

Comment: This looks like a job for `<table>`, honestly. While I'm normally loathe to use them for layout purposes, they're probably the easiest way to get what you want.

Comment: I was discussing with some front enders on IRC and ideally we would move away from tables as you can achieve responsiveness easier when not using tables. Yes easily achieved with tables though.

Comment: See [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/) for some popular techniques.

Comment: Looks like flex box may be the way to go.

Comment: Tables will make your life easier. It will 'just work' in wide viewports. When going smaller, you can simply set table cells to display as blocks. I have a simple plugin if it helps: https://github.com/kthornbloom/Responsive_Tables

Flexbox would be your other option, but it's more confusing and has less support.

Comment: The debate over using tables for layout ended about 5 years ago. There's no reason to do so, nor should you for accessibility reasons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just for completeness, I'll throw in a `flexbox` variation.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  background: #eee;
  justify-content: space-beteeen;
  align-content: center;
}
.container > div {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
.container .team {
  width: 25%;
  font-size: 150%;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.container .team:first-child {
  text-align: right;
}
.container .team:last-child {
  text-align: left;
}
.container .logo {
  width: 15%;
}
.container > div img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="team">Vasco</div>
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/1000x750" />
  </div>
  <div class="status">Finished</div>
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/1000x750" />
  </div>
  <div class="team">flamengo</div>
</div>
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jx77tuvj/9/)

Comment: What's your opinion on using flexbox in production in 2015?

Comment: I agree...if you are *only* targeting modern browsers (IE10+) then it's great.   I'm still inclined to have fallbacks though and use feature detection and a prefixing system like prefixree or autoprefixer..although SASS/LESS can handle a lot of the heavy lifting.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use tables for layout. Ever.

```
.container {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    background: #eee;
}
.container > div {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 2%;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.container > div img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jx77tuvj/5)**

Here's a version with varying widths for team and logo cells. Notice that the images behave responsively in both examples.

```
.container {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    background: #eee;
}
.container > div {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.container .team {
    width: 25%;
}
.container .logo {
    width: 15%;
}
.container > div img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

**[Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/jx77tuvj/6)**

Comment: a bit complex don't you think?

Comment: In what sense? It's quite simple in terms of markup, and the CSS covers a lot of ground. I'm eagerly awaiting for your simpler solution.

Comment: "Don't use tables for layout. Ever."...unless it's actually tabular data, of course.

Comment: Then t wouldn't be for layout, would it? It would be for semantic display. :)

Comment: I think we need to remove the display: block from the image? to have that centred also?

Comment: Ah, right. I meant `inline-block` (to remove the extender space at the bottom).

Answer (score 1):

I'll add a simple flexbox example for solving this issue, although it would require some prefixing in order to have optimal support:

```
.container {
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
}
```

And that's pretty much it. To get majority support you have to do some prefixing and fallbacks for older versions, which looks ugly but works across modern browsers:

```
.container {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -moz-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -moz-align-items: center;
  align-items: center; 
}
```

Note that browser support isn't 100% for [flexbox](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox), but I personally prefer to go with the majority support and fall back on browsers that require it.

Here is a simple demo:

```css
.container{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}
  
.container div{
  margin:10px;
}

.team1,
.team2{
  font-size:24px;
}

.logo1,
.logo2{
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  border:solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">   
  <div class="team1"> Vasco </div>  
  <div class="logo1"> <img>logo image</img> </div>   
    <div class="status"> Finished </div>
  <div class="logo2"> <img>logo image</img> </div> 
  <div class="team2"> flamengo </div> 
</div>
```